# Django AutoComplete Light Filter Foreign Key Values

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light, django-smart-selects

I am using the [Django AutoComplete Light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) library to filter Form values based on a Primary key. I have two models as below:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name



  class SubSkill(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        def __str__(self):
        return self.name.
```

However, these two field are used in another **Employee** model as I want to query base on this model. I had used [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects) to chain the models in the Employee model which works fine. However, I am trying to filter my subskills based on the skills using the Autocomplete library but getting all the subskills instead. My **Django Autocomplete light** view looks like this

```
class SubskillsAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

def get_queryset(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    # if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
    #     return Country.objects.none()

    qs = SubSkill.objects.all()

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs
```

and my model form looks like this:

```
class EmployeeSkillForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ('skills','sub_skills', 'experience','resume','certificates')
    widgets = {
        'sub_skills': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='skills-autocomplete')
    }
```

I cannot figure out why my subskills will not filter based on the skill instead of showing everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the newest version of `django-autocomplete-light` [doc](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html).
To filter results based on the value of other fields in the form you have to use `forward` argument.

The form:

```
class EmployeeSkillForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('skills','sub_skills', 'experience','resume','certificates')
        widgets = {
           'sub_skills': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='skills-autocomplete', 
                                                            forward=['skills'])
                  }
```

Django Autocomplete light view:

```
class SubskillsAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = SubSkill.objects.all()
        skills = self.forwarded.get('skills', None)

        if skills:
            qs = qs.filter(skill__in=skills)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)


        return qs
```

Comment: This worked!! Very helpful. My main challenge was working with forwarded  values and filtering subskills based on skills. Thanks again

Comment: There is a challenge though, when I try selecting the Skills I get **Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.**